# Importing excel file in rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-3, import

I am following Ryan Bates railcast tutorial for importing excel file through a rail application.
My Ruby version is 2.2.4 and rails version is 4.2.6
I installed 'roo' gem already.

My app\models\user.rb file is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'csv'

def self.import(file)

spreadsheet= open_spreadsheet(file)
header=spreadsheet.row(1)
(2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
  row=Hash[[header,spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  user=find_by_id(row["id"])||new
  user.attributes=row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
  user.save
end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  #when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new (file.path nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new (file.path)
  #when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new (file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
 end

end
```

My app\controllers\users_controller.rb file is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @users=User.all
 end
 def import
   User.import(params[:file])
   redirect_to root_url, notice: "Activity data imported!"
 end
end
```

Now my application home page is working properly. But after selectiong the file from file chooser when I am clicking on the "import excel" button (I have done all this in index.html.erb file),,then it is showing the following error:

> RuntimeError in UsersController#import
>
> could not locate a workbook, possibly an empty file passed

Can not solve this problem yet. The method open_spreadsheet is already defined there then whats the reason of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
spreadsheet= open_spreadsheet(file)
```

to:

```
spreadsheet= User.open_spreadsheet(file)
```

EDIT:
You are also missing and end:

```
def self.import(file)

spreadsheet= open_spreadsheet(file)
header=spreadsheet.row(1)
(2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
  row=Hash[[header,spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  user=find_by_id(row["id"])||new
  user.attributes=row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
  user.save
end
end #<-----------
```

EDIT:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'csv'

def self.import(file)

spreadsheet= open_spreadsheet(file)
header=spreadsheet.row(1)
(2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
  row=Hash[[header,spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
  user=find_by_id(row["id"])||new
  user.attributes=row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
  user.save
end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  #when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new (file.path nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new (file.path)
  #when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new (file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
 end

end
```

Comment: You are missing and "end" after the first each loop

Comment: now it comes with SyntaxError in UsersController#import

Comment: C:/Ruby22/rails/importcsv/app/models/user.rb:61: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Comment: no ,,,,its not working. The Syntax error is not there anymore but it has come with the old error NoMethodError in UsersController#import                                                                                  undefined method `open_spreadsheet' for #<Class:0x7c6f728>

Comment: I did not use iconiv,,because it is not working in my environment.

Comment: Yeah that was for end ..I have solved it now.Thnx @ryudice .Now I am facing a runtime error as could not locate a workbook, possibly an empty file passed